# declaring an eval() as a variable

Tags: vbscript

I have two variables in my active server page code

Dim STATE_INSPECTIONDETAILLIBELLE_(1000)
Dim ERROR_INSPECTIONDETAILLIBELLE_(1000)

and a form where i have all my variables and error check

```
some asp bla bla
do while not vrs.eof
    %>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="inspectiondetailLibelle_<%=vrs("id")%>" value="STATE_<%=trim(vrs("id"))%>">
&nbsp;<%=ERROR_inspectiondetailLibelle_<%=vrs("id")%>
    </td>
</tr>
```

so now am checking if fields are fille and not empty

```
if trim(eval("STATE_INSPECTIONDETAILLIBELLE_" & STATE_Param_Events))="" then                
   eval("ERROR_INSPECTIONDETAILLIBELLE_" & STATE_Param_Events)= "Erreur: Le libellé de la vérification ne peut pas être vide!"
 else
    update database bla bla
end if
```

My problem is that obviously my code not working, am getting error

```
type mismatch: 'Eval' in line
eval("ERROR_INSPECTIONDETAILLIBELLE_" & STATE_Param_Events)= "Erreur: Le libellé de la vérification ne peut pas être vide!"
```

How can i build my variable ERROR_ + the concatenation so that i do the right error response.write in my form

thx
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to assign a value to a dynamically named variable use `execute` instead of `eval`. Like this:

```
execute("ERROR_INSPECTIONDETAILLIBELLE_" & STATE_Param_Events & "=""Erreur: Le libellé de la vérification ne peut pas être vide!""")
```

Please note that use of `execute` is not safe, consider use of a `Scripting.Dictionary` instead.